# Update values inside while loop PHP with same ID

Tags: php, sql

Until now i can't solve my problem regarding this update by the way i have 2 columns

ID AND COLOR

In my saving i have this

```
Number of color: 4
Color 1: RED
Color 2: BLACK
Color 3: YELLOW
Color 4: BLUE
```

Now it is successfully saved in my database now i want to update color into this

```
Color 1: GREEN
Color 2: YELLOW
Color 3: BLACK
Color 4: WHITE
```

In testing phase using for loop i'm getting the right color combination

```
$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$count = count($color1);

for ($x = 0; $x <=$count; $x++) {

        echo  $savecolor = $color1[$x];
}
```

But when i add my update codes like this

```
$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$count = count($color1);

for ($x = 0; $x <=$count; $x++) {

$savecolor = $color1[$x];

$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE productcolor SET colorName = :color WHERE  productinformationID=:productinformationID');

$stmt->execute(array(':color' => $savecolor, ':productinformationID' =>$prodID));


}
```

It turn out like this

```
Color 1: WHITE
Color 2: WHITE
Color 3: WHITE
Color 4: WHITE
```

In actual database it looks like this

```
productcolorID(PK)       productinformationID(FK)       color
306                      50                             ORANGE
307                      50                             ORANGE
308                      50                             ORANGE
309                      50                             ORANGE
```

the prodID is from

```
 $prodID   = $row['productinformationID']; its equals to 50
```

Can you help me guys so my color will not copy same color in my fields. 
I have been stocked here a week. Hope you help me guys. Thank you!

Comment: where did you give `$prodID` ? and where did you assign `:colorName` ?

Comment: Please see my update update codes above.

Comment: this could be completely stupid but, can you try without the whitespace around :color (`colorName=:color`) , and also maybe add quotes/apostrophes around the value (`colorName=":color"`)
I don't know... just a suggestion to try out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Doe identified the problem: You were changing all the records with every statement because the `WHERE` clause matched them all. They all have the same `productinformationID`. That is why you saw the effect of only the last statement - it overrode all the previous.

To fix it, you need to add in the bits that identify the records uniquely.

```
$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$count = count($color1);

for ($x = 0; $x <=$count; $x++) {

    $savecolor = $color1[$x];

    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE productcolor SET colorName = :color WHERE  productinformationID=:productinformationID AND productcolorID=:productcolorID');

    $stmt->execute(array(':color' => $savecolor, ':productinformationID' =>$prodID, ':productcolorID' => $x));
}
```

(Note that what I have added to the code is at the end of the two long lines, so you will need to scroll to see it)

I do realise the value for `:productcolorID` is not exactly equal to `$x`. But that is best fixed by you.

--EDIT

Here is convenience function that may or may not be useful:

```
function fetch($query, $params=array(), $fetchMode=PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    global $db;

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    if (!$stmt->execute($params))
        return false;

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 1)
        return $stmt;

    $result = $stmt->fetch($fetchMode);

    if (count($result) > 1)
        return $result;

    return reset($result);
}
```

Using that you can get the offset to `:productcolorID` like this:

```
$offset = fetch('SELECT MIN(productcolorID) FROM productcolor WHERE productinformationID=?', array($prodId));
```

After that, the code is pretty much the same as above. The only difference is the value for `:productcolorID`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE productcolor SET colorName = :color WHERE  productinformationID=:pid AND productcolorID=:cid');

$colorsCount = count($colors);
for ($i = 0; $i < $colorsCount; $i++) {
    $color = $colors[$i];

    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':color' => $color,
        ':pid' => $prodID,
        ':cid' => $offset + $i)
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm trying the idea that you gave. Wait for a second.

Comment: @user5598179 have you tried it? I would to love to know if you managed to solve the problem

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: @user5598179 What part in particular?!

Comment: @user5598179 See the edited answer. I simulated your situation as best as I could. The code works here.  
If it works with you too, please mark the answer as `Accepted`, because this is getting annoying already.

Comment: I'm sorry if my naming convention is horrible. I'm new to PDO and I'm still learning it, again sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

Anly is on the right track.  You're updating the same record each time.  You need to specify different values for "productinformationID" and "prodID" each time you iterate the loop.

```
$colors = $_POST['colors'];
$count = count($colors);
$ids = $_POST['ids'];

for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {
    echo $colors[$x] . " " . $ids[$x] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Although I didn't quite have that in mind, I am not sure that is the problem.  
The code certainly misses the part where `productID` is defined, but if that was the problematic part, wouldn't only the first entry ever be changed?

Comment: What does the code look like with the different product IDs?

Comment: @user5598179 Can you please update your code with the parts concerning `$prodID`. Currently, it does not seem to change. John is right for believing that that is the problem.

Comment: Anly, you're right that it would only update the 1st record.

Comment: Maybe all the product records have the same product ID?  Maybe they're all blanK?  If so, that would explain the results from the code above.

Comment: Indeed. I had the same thought just now.

Comment: Yeah, we have to see where $prodID is coming from.  That will have the key to the solution.

Comment: If we add input fields for "ids", similar to "colors", that could give us the product IDs.

Comment: Well, the problem is indeed that he is updating all the records with every statement, because they all match the `WHERE` clause.
But I think your advise to use different `product**information**ID` might not be what he wants to achieve. As far as I see, he should also add `product**color**ID` in the `WHERE` clause and have an extra bound parameter `:colorID => $x`

Comment: @JohnDoe displaying the different colors from post is already working my only problem is when i'm saving it, it copies the whole values copy last color.

Comment: Do you have input fields for the IDs (like in my edited code)?

Comment: @Anly can you give me a sample codes of your thoughts?

Comment: @user5598179 I'll add another answer in a minute

Comment: Hmm.  Are the product ID values indexed in the database table?  Are they auto-increment?  Are they blank?  Are they needed?  Are there values stored anywhere else in the code?

Comment: The productID is auto increment from other table.

Answer (score 0):

Try a predefined query without a loop and all the other stuff. Just prepare a statement, and in the array of arguments (that you pass to execute) set `:color => "RED"` or whatever you are actually receiving. This will confirm that the values are valid within the SQL statement.
It could be that they are **not** valid and the default value for the field is `WHITE`, which would explain why they all become `WHITE`